# Excluded category posts from admin, add them to search

Tags: wordpress, hook

The story is like this, I wanted to createa new menu in WP Admin that displays only posts from a specific category (cat 13 in our case). While this works pretty well, the problem is, when I try to used the WP admin search, no posts from that category is displayed. I'm not sure how to approach this, at this moment I'm scratching my head.

Current code is:

```
function exclude_category_posts( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_admin()) {
    if($_REQUEST['page_type']=="single_cat")
        $query->set( 'cat', '13' );
    else
        $query->set( 'cat', '-13' );
  }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_posts' );
```

How can I do this to allow the search to look for posts from that category..or better, on that separate page I made, to make the search look only for posts from that category.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using `$query->is_search()` as part of your query?

Comment: Funny thing, I did that, however, I forgot to disable/clear xcache and didnt' work at the time. Tried it again today since It made me wonder why it didn't work and ...it works now. Thanks for reminding me lol

Comment: Cache can be a fickle friend. Glad you got it working!